# My department has changed its favorite fields of research. What are the consequences?

Tags: mathematics, united-states, professorship, research-topic

When I was hired to a math department (in the US) my field was among the favorite directions in the department. Few years later the department decided to put more attention on some other areas of math.

I am wondering what might be the practical consequences of this decision for me. E.g. whether my research will be considered to be less important for the department from some point of view? Will I get more administrative duties? Will it be harder to get grants for my research? Any other consequences?

I have a tenure position.

Comment: Are you a tenure-track faculty member? adjunct? postdoc? The "more administrative duties" point makes it unlikely you're a graduate student, but I'm guessing the answer might be a bit different depending on which of those three options you fall into.

Comment: I have tenure position.

Comment: Where does your funding come from? Department? Your own grants?

Comment: I don't think anyone can give an authoritative answer, so with regrets I voted to close.

Comment: @RoboKaren: I know the question doesn't specifically ask this, but it seems to be in the vein of "my research direction was in vogue but no longer is. What do I do?" Is there a duplicate somewhere that might then be helpful?

Comment: @RoboKaren: The answers below are quite helpful. Perhaps  there is no single answer which would work for all departments, it is interesting to learn about experiences of different people from different places. So why to close?

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid I find the question rather vague.  You write

> When I was hired to a math department (in the US) my field was among the favorite directions in the department.

I have spent my entire professional life in math departments in the US, and I was not aware that they (we?) have "favorite directions."  Even the smallest departments I know have at least four different research areas represented, and the general attitude / expectation is that everyone should be collegial and helpful with each other while feeling that their own area is the "favorite" and promoting accordingly.

It is true that often different research groups have different sizes or different profiles.  In my department for instance the number theory group has been larger than the analysis group (and had more students, offered more courses, organized more conferences and so forth...) in the time I've been there.  But there is no *explicit, systemic way* in which number theory is promoted over analysis in my department: in fact we have hired in both groups in recent years.

> Few years later the department decided to put more attention on some other areas of math.

Again, what does that mean?  Do you mean in terms of hiring initiatives?  If so, maybe you have nothing to worry about: hiring initiatives are very often cyclic: departments target areas where the ranks have shrunk in recent years.  I have never in my life heard of a hiring initiative whose express purpose is to deemphasize or somehow lessen in any way the stature of faculty who are already there.  Why in the world would a department agree to that?  Even if a "lessening" of a current research area was in the best interest of the majority of the current members, faculty have more solidarity and longsighted worries than that: [first they came for the analysts...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_they_came_...)

> E.g. whether my research will be considered to be less important for the department from some point of view? Will I get more administrative duties? Will it be harder to get grants for my research? Any other consequences?

Again, it seems really impossible for us to answer these questions.  The first one is excruciatingly vague. Everyone's research may be considered to be less important for the department *from some point of view*: if it's too theoretical then how is it contributing to the world really, and if it's overly applied then it's, you know, not as cool to pure mathematicians.  Will you get more administrative duties is certainly a question to ask the other members of your department.  I don't really understand why this would affect your ability to get external grants, but then I don't really understand what you're talking about.

In general this is something that as a tenured professor you absolutely need to discuss with your colleagues.  Honestly, you sound like you don't understand the whole thing very well.  I urge you to get a clue by talking to your colleagues, repeatedly and protractedly if necessary.  Being tenured means your colleagues need to listen and address *all* your questions and concerns.  It's time for you to use that power.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First when I am asking about consequences, I do not mean that they should always be explicitly stated. Say, on my department it was stated explicitly by some important professor that field A is important and we will keep hiring experts in this field. And this is what actually happens for the last few years. At the same time, the number of colloquium talks related to this field has increased. Of course  nobody stated explicitly that other fields are less important. However my impression is that they became less visible just because preference was given to other fields.

Comment: Thus naturally I am wondering what might be the other possible consequences. (In fact you are right, for some reasons I do not understand very well how the system works.)

Comment: @user65203 What do you mean by "some important professor"? What sort of additional power does this person have in decisions related to hiring new faculty and arranging colloquia compared to an ordinary professor?

Comment: I agree with @Tobias's question (if that makes sense).  If it's just a matter of individual faculty members trying to push the center of mass of the department in a certain direction: well yes, that is very common and I alluded to it in my answer.  Just because someone says "we will keep hiring experts in this field" doesn't make it true; other people say the same thing about their field...including you.  The bottom line is: **you're in the department**, so it's your responsibility to steer it in the direction you think is best.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Well, as far as I heard on some departments there is a small group of leaders which, among other things, is more involved in identifying hiring directions. This is what I mean by 'important professor'. Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Others have pointed out the vagueness of the question. I'll set that aside for a second and respond to the questions by making some specific assumptions that I may or may not (be able to) articulate. I warn you that my view is not only glass-half-empty, it's glass-half-empty-with-putrid-slime.

First, in my field, setting or resetting research areas at the department level are common but significant. They take place regularly enough and have variable success. For example, a change in university research strategy will initiate a round of reassessments of department level strategies. The arrival of a new department head may be another cause for a reassessment.

When a reassessment of department research strategy takes place, there is often stakeholder consultation. The breadth, level and quality of this consultation is, as you can imagine, highly variable. It may also be quite meaningless, especially in the case of faux attempts at consultation. It seems to me that you were not satisfied with this consultation. Whether you were consulted at all or whether you chose not to participate is not a point I would wish to consider here.

In my experience, it is quite difficult to alter drastically the course of a vessel as complex as a department due to the extreme levels of inertia. Thus, for this to take place, at least two things must be present: (1) there are or will be major perturbations in the academic field making the present course riskier than changing course and (2) there must be support at the senior levels of the university. The reason, I'm sorry to say, is simple: it's boils down to the metrics against which each department is assessed -- students, research output, grant success, esteem measures and philanthropy. What I'm saying is that someone's made a determination somewhere that change is better than no change. Again, I won't go into the fairness or appropriateness of these here.

In my experience (I repeat, this is **my** experience) of having witnessed first hand the effect of research direction on a number of departments, I can provide these insights:

1. **Change will hurt some, please others and not affect many.** A change in research direction will result in the loss of some academics on non-permanent contracts. It is unlikely that anyone will be fired, simply that their contracts will not be renewed. Nevertheless, the trauma can be significant. On the other hand, the new directions will result in a hiring bonanza for others. Finally, the reason it won't affect many is because the work of the department needs to continue. For a department with an undergraduate teaching program, for example, you still need non-specialists to teach the basic subjects, you'll still need lab technicians, etc.
2. **Permanent personnel will see changes to their workloads.** This will be negotiated through performance review procedures. The form and nature of these changes may be minor or major. Noncompliance will be handled through the university disciplinary system. In some extreme cases, I have observed situations in which entire sections (or labs) have been closed and permanent personnel offered redundancy packages. Area studies in the humanities is a recent example of this.
3. **There will be a period in which departures exceeds arrivals.** In my experience, the period prior to and including the transition phase witnesses the tyranny of mediocrity. The brightest leave for greener pastures and the dimmest are put out to pasture. Those that are left behind are those that can't or won't move. Those who are retained will need to take up the slack of those who've left.
4. **The darling cash cows will be preserved.** A department rarely refuses the receipt of competitive grant funding. Especially in the case of superstar academics, it is likely that such programs will be rolled into the new research strategy.
5. **There will be a period of recovery until the next dimwit comes along and decides it's a great idea to change research direction.**

Good luck to you.

Comment: I think that much of this has limited relevance to math departments, where there are usually very few (or no) long-term non-permanent faculty involved in research, and grant funding is too insignificant (compared to experimental sciences) to play a very large role in strategic decisions.